# Uniform arrival times at a bus stop

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> 40 people arrives at a bus stop at a uniform continuous time between
> 8:00 and 8:15. The bus arrives at the stop at 8:10, 8:12, and 8:15
> with probabilities 0.3, 0.5, and 0.2, respectively and takes everyone
> at the stop. Let X be the number of people taking the bus. What is the expectation and variance of X?

Intuitively, I am getting $E(X)=40*(0.3*10/15+0.5*12/15+0.2*15/15)=32$. But how can I get the pdf of X to calculate the expectation and variance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y \in \{1, 2, 3\}$ represent the arrival time of the bus, with $Y = 1$ representing 8:10, and $Y = 2$ representing 8:12, and $Y = 3$ representing 8:15.  Then $$\Pr[Y = 1] = 0.3 \\ \Pr[Y = 2] = 0.5 \\ \Pr[Y = 3] = 0.2.$$  We want to compute $\Pr[X = x]$, the unconditional PMF of the number of passengers the bus takes.  To this end, we condition on $Y$.  For instance, $\Pr[X = x \mid Y = 1]$ represents the probability that exactly $x$ people arrive at the stop by 8:10.  Since the arrivals are uniformly distributed from 8:00 to 8:15, each person arriving has a $2/3$ probability of arriving within the first 10 minutes, and each person's arrival is independent of the arrivals of the other people.  Thus, $$X \mid Y = 1 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 40, p_1 = 2/3)$$ with
$$\Pr[X = x \mid Y = 1] = \binom{40}{x} (2/3)^x (1/3)^{40-x}.$$  Similarly, $$X \mid Y = 2 \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 40, p_2 = 4/5).$$  In the final case, $X \mid Y = 3$ is not random: we have $\Pr[X = 40 \mid Y = 3] = 1$, since everyone is assured to arrive by 8:15.  Then by the law of total probability,
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[X = x] &= \sum_{y=1}^3 \Pr[X = x \mid Y = y]\Pr[Y = y] \\
&= \binom{40}{x} \left( \frac{3}{10} (2/3)^x (1/3)^{40-x} + \frac{1}{2} (4/5)^x (1/5)^{40-x} + \frac{1}{5} \mathbb 1(x = 40) \right). \\
\end{align}$$

This PMF does not need to be calculated in order to compute the expectation and variance.  To get the expectation, we apply the law of total expectation:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{E}[X] &= \sum_{y=1}^3 \operatorname{E}[X \mid Y = y]\Pr[Y = y] \\
&= n p_1 \Pr[Y = 1] + n p_2 \Pr[Y = 2] + n \Pr[Y = 3] \\
&= 40((2/3)(3/10) + (4/5)(1/2) + (1/5)) \\
&= 32.
\end{align}$$
Then to compute the variance, we calculate $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = \sum_{y=1}^3 \operatorname{E}[X^2 \mid Y = y]\Pr[Y = y]$$ in the same manner as above, noting that for a binomial random variable, $\operatorname{E}[X^2] = np(1-p) + n^2 p^2$.  Then we finally use $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2.$$

---

For the sake of curiosity, the PMF for $X$ is shown in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \Pr[X = x] \\
\hline
 0 & 2.467579 \times 10^{-20} \\
 1 & 1.974063 \times 10^{-18} \\
 2 & 7.698847 \times 10^{-17} \\
 3 & 1.950374 \times 10^{-15} \\
 4 & 3.608193 \times 10^{-14} \\
 5 & 5.195798 \times 10^{-13} \\
 6 & 6.061765 \times 10^{-12} \\
 7 & 5.888572 \times 10^{-11} \\
 8 & 4.858073 \times 10^{-10} \\
 9 & 3.454632 \times 10^{-9} \\
 10 & 2.141874 \times 10^{-8} \\
 11 & 1.168298 \times 10^{-7} \\
 12 & 5.646798 \times 10^{-7} \\
 13 & 2.432489 \times 10^{-6} \\
 14 & 9.382629 \times 10^{-6} \\
 15 & 0.0000325276 \\
 16 & 0.000101656 \\
 17 & 0.000287071 \\
 18 & 0.000733841 \\
 19 & 0.00170041 \\
 20 & 0.00357503 \\
 21 & 0.00682546 \\
 22 & 0.0118443 \\
 23 & 0.0187105 \\
 24 & 0.0269928 \\
 25 & 0.0357957 \\
 26 & 0.0441756 \\
 27 & 0.0517703 \\
 28 & 0.0591383 \\
 29 & 0.067258 \\
 30 & 0.076186 \\
 31 & 0.0838148 \\
 32 & 0.0861411 \\
 33 & 0.079579 \\
 34 & 0.0639085 \\
 35 & 0.0432651 \\
 36 & 0.0238812 \\
 37 & 0.0102935 \\
 38 & 0.00324528 \\
 39 & 0.000665157 \\
 40 & 0.200066 \\
\end{array}$$